# Does Cn1 support serial ports?

Tags: codenameone

I will need the ability to communicate with a device attached via USB that shows up as a serial port.  Is this possible with cn1?  I haven't seen any reference to it.  Does the native java import javax.comm.*; work on all platforms?

Answer (score 0):

No, comm isn't portable. You would be able to bundle it into the desktop port but you'd need a different implementation for everything else using the native interfaces.

Before we had builtin support for sockets Steve created a cn1lib for socket support which you can use as a reference to how one would implement streaming data over native interfaces